# Is there any easy way to copy QPainter state?

Tags: qt

I want to implment push_group/pop_group of cairo with QPainter, but QPainter resets all its state while begin() with a new painterDevice, so I have to save/revert all state manually.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just check out [`QPainter::save()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#save) and [`QPainter::restore()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#restore).

If you want to save/restore between the lifespan of multiple QPainters, you have to do it manually. You could just create a class `PainterState` that encapsulates the painter state (pen, brush, transform, etc.), and then store a `QStack<PainterState>`.

There is a QPainterState class, but it is for internal use only, and I think it's only for use with a single QPainter. See the source ("qpainter_p.h") if you're interested in the QPainterState members (too many to copy here).

Comment: so, when I begin() on a new device, the saved state will be still there?  save() begin() restore() will do the job?

Comment: @feverzsj I don't think so. If you're using multiple devices, you have to manage the state yourself. But, like I said, creating your own `QStack<PainterState>` should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

When constructing the QPainter object, you can draw it to a [QPicture](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpicture.html). Then it can be reloaded when needed and painted out to the real QPaintDevice.

```
QPicture picture;
QPainter painterQueued;
painterQueued.begin(&picture);           // paint in picture
painterQueued.drawEllipse(10,20, 80,70); // draw an ellipse
painterQueued.end();                     // painting done

QImage myImage;
QPainter painterTarget;
painterTarget.begin(&myImage);               // paint in myImage
painterTarget.drawPicture(0, 0, picture);    // draw the picture at (0,0)
painterTarget.end();                         // painting done
```

You could queue up many QPicture objects in a list, stack, etc, and replay them when needed.